# Proving (or refuting) TU (totally unimodularity) of a matrix nxm

Tags: functions, matrix

I am new to Mathematica and want to prove the totally unimodularity of a matrix (not a particular one, but for any matrix input).

> A matrix A is totally unimodular (TU) if every square submatrix of A
> has determinant −1, 0 or +1.

So far, I have calculated the determinant of my matrix. Then, I got the minors of my matrix, but since my original matrix of dimension *nxm* is not square, the determinant minors are not necessarily square matrices.

Disclaimer: This is not for homework or a test, but for my own project. And I also want to learn mathematica for future stuff because I think it is an astonishing tool for future works I would like to explore.

Comment: What about `Minors[matrix, 4, Det]`?

Comment: Would that calculate all possible determinants of matrix 4x4?

Comment: Much easier if you work mod 3. Just saying.

Comment: Could you elaborate? please

Comment: It was intended in jest. Mod 3 all minors are 0, 1 or -1.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT 1: thanks to the user @orpanter, author of the OP, for running the diagnostics and checking that the suggested solution indeed works correctly.**

We code in a matrix

```
matrix = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {7, 8, 9, 10}, {5, 4, 3, 2}, {11, 9, 6, 
    5}, {12, 13, 3, 4}, {1, 0, 14, 4}};
```

[image: matrix]

with `Dimensions` given by

```
matrix // Dimensions
```

> `{6, 4}`

From the documentation, we know that [`Subsets`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Subsets.html) *gives a list of all possible subsets of list.*

```
subsets = Subsets[matrix];
```

From the above sublists, we keep only the ones that are square

```
res = Select[subsets, SquareMatrixQ[##] &];
```

and then we calculate their determinants

```
Det /@ res
```

> `{0, 0, 0, -66, 36, -594, -66, 36, -594, -1375, -132, 72, -1188, -2593, 157}`

**Edit 2: substantial edit**

After the comments, the matrix we consider here is given by:

```
matrix = {{1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1}, {0, -1, 0, 0, 
    1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 1}, {A, 0, 
    1, A/B, 0, 0, 0}, {B, 0, B/A, 1, 0, 0, 0}};

Dimensions@matrix
MatrixForm@matrix
```

> `{7, 7}`

> [image: 7by7]

For the reader's convenience, the task at hand is to compute the determinant of the initial/seed matrix and all submatrices. Hence, we need to compute ***ALL SQUARE*** submatrices.

- Step 1: Computing the determinant of the seed matrix just to get it out of the way:

  Det@matrix

> `0`

- Step 2:  Previously, I suggested [`Subsets`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Subsets.html), but upon reflection I think that the way to go about it is [`Minors`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Minors.html).

For the seed $7 \times 7$ matrix we run

```
obo = Minors[matrix, 1, Identity];
tbt = Minors[matrix, 2, Identity];
ttbtt = Minors[matrix, 3, Identity];
fbf = Minors[matrix, 4, Identity];
ffbff = Minors[matrix, 5, Identity];
sbs = Minors[matrix, 6, Identity];
```

To obtain all the sub-ones. The outputs are large, however, for display purposes one can try for instance

```
Grid@Partition[MatrixForm /@ sbs[[1]], 5]
```

and for `sbs[[2]]` etc up until `sbs[[Length@sbs]]`. The output of the above looks as follows:

[image: sbs[1]]

Thus, we have obtained all $1 \times 1$, $2 \times 2$, etc.

- Step 3: computing their determinants.

A demonstration for the $1 \times 1$ cases.

```
obo
```

returns

> `{{{{1}}, {{1}}, {{1}}, {{1}}, {{0}}, {{0}}, {{0}}}, {{{1}}, {{0}}, \ {{0}}, {{0}}, {{1}}, {{1}}, {{1}}}, {{{0}}, {{-1}}, {{0}}, {{0}}, \ {{1}}, {{0}}, {{0}}}, {{{0}}, {{0}}, {{-1}}, {{0}}, {{0}}, {{1}}, \ {{0}}}, {{{0}}, {{0}}, {{0}}, {{-1}}, {{0}}, {{0}}, {{1}}}, {{{A}}, \ {{0}}, {{1}}, {{A/B}}, {{0}}, {{0}}, {{0}}}, {{{B}}, {{0}}, {{B/ A}}, {{1}}, {{0}}, {{0}}, {{0}}}}`

and we can calculate and display the determinants as follows:

```
Grid@Partition[Table[Det /@ obo[[i]], {i, 1, Length@obo}], 4]
```

[image: obodets]

The $2 \times 2$ cases

```
Grid@Partition[Table[Det /@ tbt[[i]], {i, 1, Length@tbt}], 4]
```

[image: tbtdets]

Comment: I try it with an example I had done by hand and its exactly what I wanted!! Thank you so much for being so detailed in the steps!! I learn a lot!!

Comment: @orpanter glad to hear that there are no mistakes. in my response. Good luck with your studies/projects and please do consider accepting the answer :-)

Comment: I will! But one quick question before, if the output is only {0}, it means that all solutions from where the same and equal to 0?

Comment: I use it for this matrix={{1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1}, {0, -1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
  0}, {0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 1}, {A, 0, 1, A/B, 
  0, 0, 0}, {B, 0, B/A, 1, 0, 0, 0}}

Comment: @orpanter many thanks for the feedback and for providing the explicit matrix. I will make sure to have a look a bit later. Just a quick comment. The output `{0}` is informing you that you obtained a list, with one element precisely, that is equal to `0`.

Comment: Okey! I also tried for a non-square matrix, and it got me an empty in res {}. Which is weird, I will also read documentation to try to understand what's going on. I can't put the matrix here because it surpasses the characters limit :c

Comment: @orpanter if you observe the matrix in the answer is *ALSO* non-square. That was on purpose, since you had mentioned it as a requirement in the description of the OP. it might be a glitch or something

Comment: @orpanter can you please have a look at the edit 2 and let me know your thoughts? I tried the $7 \times 7$ matrix with the unknowns `A` and `B` you provided. The edited version seems to make sense, as we get relations for the unknowns, as expected. I tried for the non-square matrix as well and seems to be working, i.e the matrix from my original response. Many thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see with Mathematica the original matrix A must be tall and thin for your setup to work. If you have a short and fat matrix B as the original - take its transpose C = Transpose[B] (since if B is TUM its transpose is also TUM). Then apply the steps to validate TUM property.